# how do I get subcollection path in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I'm fairly new to firebase and I'm trying to get the path to one of my subcollections in order to install a firebase extension.

This is how my JSON looks like

[image: firebase-image]

The issue is I'm trying to get the subcollection "comments" under each "post" document as required by the extension

[image: extension-configuration]

I'm aware I can use collection groups and simply give it "comments" however in my case the path is required by the extension

I tried doing `post/comments` however it would detect that the path is incorrect and would throw out an error

I tried `post/${postId}/comments` however that simply wouldn't work

I know the extension does work because something like `/post/c9902c40-6e63-11ed-b700-2d9d4e8231b7/comments` does work for that one branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to enter would be called a "[collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)", which is all of the collections with the same name, no matter where they are located. This extension is asking you for just a collection, which means you can specify only one complete path without wildcards (it can't be a collection group).  I'd suggest sending feedback to the author of the plugin and ask for collection group support.  I'm guessing you're using this one:

https://github.com/conversationai/firestore-perspective-toxicity

Either that, or put all comment documents in a single collection and point the extension there instead.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the extension is written. For example the `firestore-bigquery-export` extension takes `posts/{postId}/comments`.

https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/functions/src/index.ts#L47

You can inspect the extension's source code and see how the value passed-in is used to see if it's supported.

Edit: looks like you are using the perspective API extension. So you can find how the collection path is used here:
https://github.com/conversationai/firestore-perspective-toxicity/blob/main/extension.yaml#L46